# VS Code: How can I keep my Apex class problems from disappearing upon edits?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

When deploying apex code with errors in it through SFDX, VS Code displays a handy list with convenient click-to-view functionality.

But, as soon as I start to edit my file for the first problem, all the problems disappear off the list.

Is it possible to keep problems from disappearing until the next time I deploy?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the salesforce vscode extension and you should outline the problem in the open source project [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues)

I got around some of these problems by creating my own extension which seems to work for me .I open sourced and made it available [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MohithShrivastava.dx-code-companion).Feel free to use it along with salesforce extension .